# Getting value from an array of keys for a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In PHP, I have a search function that will perform a stripos search in a multidimensional array (that is very deep) and if the value is found, it will return an array with the keys.  For example, the return array will look like this:

```
$my_results = array(0 => 'text', 1 => '17', 2 => 'tspan', 3 => '8', 4 => 'red');
```

The values are the keys from the multidimensional array.

How do I programmatically reference these keys to retrieve the value? (Also, the depth of the array may change and is not known).

Hardcoding like this works:

```
echo $my_array['text'][17]['tspan'][8]['red']; // displays the value
```

but, I would like to retrieve the value from the keys given in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$arrayNode = $myDeeplyNestedArray;
foreach($myArrayKeys as $key) {
    $arrayNode = $arrayNode[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply. I assume the $myArrayKeys is the array of keys that I have received from my search function? And $myDeeplyNestedArray  is the full multidimensional array that was originally searched?

Comment: That's right, I'd tried to make the variable names that I used meaningful

Comment: That worked!  I learned something new today... I swear I tried different combinations but nothing seemed to work.  THANKS!